# How to create service project without any activity?

Tags: android

Just starting with android. 
I try to create project that will send notification ( some bit for example ) to my FTP server every 3 hours.

I don't know how to create this project because each time i create new android project i must have only project with activity - and i don't need any activity - just need a service that will run when i install it on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each time i create new android project i must have only project with activity

If you are using Eclipse, uncheck the "Create activity" checkbox that tells the new project wizard to create an activity.

If you are using **`android create project`**, yes, it will create an activity for you. You can delete the Java class and the manifest `<activity>` entry if you want.

In reality, you will wind up leaving all of it alone.

> just need a service that will run when i install it on the device.

First, a service does not run just because you install it on the device. It only runs if you write code to cause it to run.

Second, while you might think "well, I will just get control at boot time and start the service then", that is possible, but it will not work on Android 3.1+ devices unless the user has run an activity first. This is to prevent "drive-by" malware.

So, I suggest that you leave the activity in there, if you want your app to work.

Moreover, unless this app is only for yourself, your users need the activity, to:

- Control the behavior of the service, such as changing the "every 3 hours" setting to something they prefer
- Read your license agreement
- Read your documentation, including how to get support
- Etc.